# Does Cloning a Salesforce Sandbox Copy ALL Data and Metadata?

Tags: sandbox-clone

I will be cloning a Partial-Dev box to another Partial-Dev box. I'm trying to understand if all data will be copied over along with configurations and metadata in executing a clone of a sandbox.

Are there any limits or restrictions I should be aware of?

Answer (score 4):

The source org doesn't matter for purposes of cloning. Cloning *to* a Partial Sandbox will copy up to 10k records per selected object in the template, plus Documents, and Attachments up to 5GB. If the source org was a Partial Sandbox and no records were added, then the answer would be "yes," but if you have loaded more than that, you'll still only the maximum number of records and data specified in [Considerations for Partial Copy sandbox creation and refreshes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381868&type=1).

Answer (score 3):

All of the metadata and data will be copied except for chatter and object history.

You can read more in the official [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_clone.htm&type=5)